# Поменять изображение при переходе на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery

к примеру переходим на данную страницу относительно домена "сайт.ру/10" и нужно поменять цвет header'a

```
if(window.location.pathname == /10) {
    $('header').css('background', 'red);
}
```

выводит

Invalid regular expression: missing /

ничего не понимаю, поставил "/". В общем нужна помощь

Comment: /10 -это что вообще такое ? не строка не число, не регулярка... определитесь с чем сравнивать надо

Comment: попробуйте `window.location.pathname == "/10/"`

Comment: а на стороне сервера вы это сделать не можете при генерации html? зачем это делать на клиенте, при том что сначала все равно покажатся дефолтный цвет, а потом он сменится на новый

Comment: @yolosora спасибо, помогло

Comment: @teran тоже хороший способ, только не знаю как. в js думал проще прописать условие если такая ссылка, то тогда определенный цвет или изображение

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych хорошее замечание, спасибо. в начале изучения js, поэтому возникают такие вопросы